# RTK polling and stopping

Tags: reactjs, next.js, rtk-query

I'm trying to stop polling an RTK query, I checked the skip parameter but I'm lost on how to implement it as the data received by the query is very strange.
Here's my code :

```
    const [skip, setSkip] = useState(false);
    const { data, error, isError, isLoading, refetch } = useGetReportsQuery({},{ pollingInterval: 15000, skip: skip });
console.log("DATA:", data);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (data != undefined) {
            console.log("DATA INSIDE USEEFFECT:", data);
            if(data.some(item => item.status !== "done")) {console.log("polling"); setSkip(false);}
            else {
                console.log("stop polling");
                setSkip(true)}
        }
    }, [data]);
```

What I don't understand is the results on the console :

```
DATA: undefined
Reports.js?ea4a:25 DATA: undefined
Reports.js?ea4a:25 DATA: []
Reports.js?ea4a:30 DATA INSIDE USEEFFECT: []
Reports.js?ea4a:33 stop polling
Reports.js?ea4a:25 DATA: undefined
```

So why I'm not getting data [] at the last line ? why is it undefined ?
And how can I get it to have [] (or whatever is returned by the api)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok so that was fast, I found [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/r4m2r?file=/src/App.tsx) and adapted it so if anyone has the issue, here's the solution, that is not to play with skip but to change the polling interval to zero.

Here's working code :

const [skip, setSkip] = useState(false); // to stop polling
const [pollingInterval, setPollingInterval] = useState(10000); // to stop polling

```
 const { data, error, isError, isLoading, refetch } = useGetReportsQuery({},{ pollingInterval: pollingInterval});

    console.log("DATA:", data);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data != undefined) {
            console.log("DATA INSIDE USEEFFECT:", data);
            if(data.some(item => item.status !== "done")) {console.log("polling");}
            else {
                console.log("stop polling");
                // setSkip(true)
                setPollingInterval(0)
            }
        }
    }, [data]);
```